# jpa: perform case insensitive order by

Tags: jpa

I have the following query:

```
select p from Plan as p where p.location = :location order by p.name
```

The problem is that if there are three plans as follows:
Apple
bat
atom
Butter

The following is returned:
Apple
Butter
atom
bat

I require the following:
Apple
atom
bat
Butter

Answer (score 15, accepted):

For example with Hibernate you can use LOWER function to p.name in ORDER BY:

```
select p from Plan as p where p.location = :location order by LOWER(p.name)
```

I assume above is not guaranteed to work with all JPA implementations, because argument to ORDER BY is not one of the following:

1. A state_field_path_expression that evaluates to an orderable state field of an entity or
   embeddable class abstract schema type designated in the SELECT clause by one of the following:
   • a general_identification_variable
   • a single_valued_object_path_expression
2. A state_field_path_expression that evaluates to the same state field of the same entity or
   embeddable abstract schema type as a state_field_path_expression in the SELECT clause
3. A result_variable that refers to an orderable item in the SELECT clause for which the same
   result_variable has been specified. This may be the result of an aggregate_expression, a
   scalar_expression, or a state_field_path_expression in the SELECT clause.
   For example, the four queries below are legal.

If it does not work with JPA implementation you use, you have to use following query:

```
select p, LOWER(p.name) AS name_order 
from Plan as p 
where p.location = :location order by name_order
```

Drawback is that result of the query is list of object arrays, first element in each list being instance of Plan entity and second element to be discarded.

Comment: your second method gives me the error 'unexpected token: LOWER'. It seems like it doesn't matter where i use LOWER or UPPER, it always gives me an error. This makes case unsensitive sorting impossible for me and is a very huge problem at the moment..

Comment: did you solve the problem with case insensitive search?

Comment: LOWER does not work in combination with column alias. I select a complex subquery for the result and want to order by this column. Duplicating this subquery with LOWER would be redundant code and possibly inefficient. Is there a way to case insensitively order by an already selected column? Maybe DB specific features?

Answer (score 5):

Following gets results sorted by 'orderField' case insensitive

```
CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<MyEntity> cq = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(MyEntity.class);
Root<MyEntity> root = cq.from(MyEntity.class);
cq.select(root).where(...).orderBy(cb.desc(cb.upper(duplicate.get(MyEntity_.orderField))));
TypedQuery<MyEntity> query = entityManager.createQuery(cq);
query.getResultList();
```

It's like telling the query to convert all characters to uppercase prior sorting

Comment: Could you please help me: if I am using a `join` just for the sorting purpose like this `criteria.orderBy(cb.asc(root.join("joinColumn").get("sortingParam")))`, how would you use the `cb.upper` in that expression? `criteria.orderBy(cb.asc(cb.upper(root.join("joinColumn").get("sortingParam"))))` appears to be a wrong usage.

Comment: where's `duplicate.get(MyEntity_.orderField)` coming from?

Answer (score 1):

Case insensitive ordering can be achieved using `OrderBy` annotation by wrapping ordering column with `LOWER` or `UPPER`

```
@OrderBy("UPPER(firstName) ASC")
private List<User> members = new ArrayList<User>();
```

Below SQL generated by hibernate

```
SELECT user0_.id AS id1_0_0_,
       user0_.firstname AS firstname2_0_1_,
       user0_.lastname AS lastname3_0_1_
FROM user user0_
WHERE user0_.user_id=?
ORDER BY upper(user0_.firstname)
```