# JPQL query: use ORDER BY case insensitively

Tags: sql, jakarta-ee, jpa, jpql, openjpa

Using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9934494/jpa-perform-case-insensitive-order-by) thread (which is very helpful) so I do the same to may jpql query(very simple, just select all record but need to sorted by 'NAME' field):

```
SELECT o, LOWER(o.name) AS nameInOrder FROM UserGroup o ORDER BY nameInOrder ASC
```

I am using openjpa, and unfortunately the application gives me

```
 java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to com.myname.app.UserGroup
```

The code running the whole jpql is like this:

```
public static List<UserGroup> findAllUserGroups(){
    return entityManager().createQuery("SELECT o, LOWER(o.name) AS nameInOrder FROM UserGroup o ORDER BY nameInOrder ASC", UserGroup.class).getResultList();
}
```

My guessing, is seems entityManager take `o` as an object but `LOWER(o.name)` as another?

Please help, really dont see any problem but OpenJPA(v2.2) doesn't coorperate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the thread you linked to, the return type from this query is `List<Object[]>` and not `List<UserGroup>`.

One otion is to leave the query as-is and pull out the `UserGroup`s from the List by looping over it:

```
List<Object[]> results = entityManager().createQuery("SELECT o, LOWER(o.name) AS nameInOrder FROM UserGroup o ORDER BY nameInOrder ASC", UserGroup.class).getResultList();
List<UserGroup> userGroups = new ArrayList<UserGroup>();
for(Object[] result : results) {
    userGroups.add( result[0] );
}
return userGroups;
```

Comment: That's very good finding! I was so dump that didn't finish the whole answer on that thread :)

Answer (score 0):

For the record, here is my implementation following jonc's advice

```
// find all groups in order
public static List<UserGroup> findAllUserGroups(){
    List<Object> results = entityManager().createQuery("SELECT o, LOWER(o.name) AS nameInOrder FROM UserGroup o ORDER BY nameInOrder ASC", Object.class).getResultList();
    List<UserGroup> userGroups = new ArrayList<UserGroup>();
    for(Object result : results) {
        Object[] resultArray = (Object[])result;
        userGroups.add((UserGroup)resultArray[0]);
    }
    return userGroups;
}
```

Consider `result` is each recordset getting back from the query

```
resultArray[0] is `o`,
resultArray[1] is `LOWER(o.name) AS nameInOrder`, which can be ignored and only use for ordering purpose.
```