# JPA - case unsensitive ORDER BY clause

Tags: java, jpa, case, jpql

I need an case unsensitive ORDER BY-clause within JPA. Somehow it doesn't work. I tried several ways, from nslsort till lower(fieldname), nothing works since I always get the same error: "expecting IDENTIFIER, found 'lower'", which means I can't use anything but the actual field name behind ORDER BY.

But there has to be a way to make this work. it needs to go along with some WHERE-clauses, depending on the user input.

---

@Neil Stockholm:
That was not an example of a query I used. I just explained that i tried the option with nlssort and various others including lower() and upper() functions. here is an example of what I've tried so far (o.ACTIVITY_NAME is a java.lang.String):

```
SELECT o, LOWER(o.ACTIVITY_NAME) as NAME_ORDER FROM Dbrd o ORDER BY ORDER_NAME asc
```

This throws the error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: line 1: unexpected token: LOWER
```

The next thing I tried was the following:

```
SELECT o FROM Dbrd o ORDER BY LOWER(o.ACTIVITY_NAME) asc
```

This throws the following error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: line 1: expecting IDENTIFIER, found 'lower'
```

I hope this helps you and all the other people here so you can help me with this matter. Unfortunately  I really don't know what to try. Everything failed so far.

---

Dbrd Class:

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.util.Date;

import javax.persistence.*;
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name="getDbrdData", query="SELECT o FROM Dbrd o")
})

/**
 * @author t.kuess
 *
 */
@Entity
@Table(name = "KORE_RU_DBRD_VIEW")
public class Dbrd implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public Dbrd() {
        super();
    }

    @Column(name = "LOWER_AUFTRAGGEBER")
    private String LOWER_AUFTRAGGEBER;

    @Column(name = "LOWER_ACTIVITY_NAME")
    private String LOWER_ACTIVITY_NAME;

    @Column(name = "LOWER_ORDER_NAME")
    private String LOWER_ORDER_NAME;

    @Column(name = "ORDER_ID")
    private BigInteger ORDER_ID;

    @Column(name = "ORDER_ID_LONG")
    private String ORDER_ID_LONG;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "ACTIVITY_ID")
    private String ACTIVITY_ID;

    @Column(name = "ACTIVITY_ID_LONG")
    private String ACTIVITY_ID_LONG;

    @Column(name = "ACTIVITY_NAME")
    private String ACTIVITY_NAME;

    @Column(name = "ACTIVITY_STATUS_ID")
    private String ACTIVITY_STATUS_ID;

    @Column(name = "BOOKING_NUMBER_SAP")
    private String BOOKING_NUMBER_SAP;

    @Column(name = "SUPPLIER_ID")
    private String SUPPLIER_ID;

    @Column(name = "SUPPLIER_NAME")
    private String SUPPLIER_NAME;

    @Column(name = "ACTIVITY_AMOUNT_DEF_CURR")
    private BigDecimal ACTIVITY_AMOUNT_DEF_CURR;

    @Column(name = "ACTIVITY_AMOUNT")
    private BigDecimal ACTIVITY_AMOUNT;

    @Column(name = "CUR_NAME")
    private String CUR_NAME;

    @Column(name = "SERVICE_MONTH")
    private String SERVICE_MONTH;

    @Column(name = "PAYMENT_DATE_SAP")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date PAYMENT_DATE_SAP;

    @Column(name = "ORDER_NAME")
    private String ORDER_NAME;

    @Column(name = "COSTCENTER")
    private String COSTCENTER;

    @Column(name = "AUFTRAGGEBER")
    private String AUFTRAGGEBER;

    @Column(name = "KST_AUFTRAGGEBER")
    private String KST_AUFTRAGGEBER;

    @Column(name = "SERVICE_START")
    private String SERVICE_START;

    @Column(name = "SERVICE_END")
    private String SERVICE_END;

    @Column(name = "ORDER_AMOUNT_DEF_CUR")
    private BigDecimal ORDER_AMOUNT_DEF_CUR;

    @Column(name = "ORDER_AMOUNT")
    private BigDecimal ORDER_AMOUNT;
```

NOTE: I didn't post all the getters and setters. They exist and they are generated from the fields you see above.

Comment: possible duplicate of [jpa: perform case insensitive order by](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9934494/jpa-perform-case-insensitive-order-by)

Comment: Tried both solutions stated there - both gave me the error 'unexpected token' or the error stated in the original question.

Comment: since when has JPQL started with FROM ? there is no "till" in JPQL. Perhaps you can start by posting your entity and then your JPQL. Then post the SQL that the JPA implementation generated, and mention what is the JPA implementation

Comment: and can you post the "Dbrd" class? The JPA implementation I use handles things like the first one fine. You don't say which one you're using

Comment: You can see the Dbrd-Class in the Question-Post now. We are using SAP JPA.