# Sorting results from NamedQuery in JPA

Tags: java, sorting, jpa

I want to execute a named query to retrieve some data

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "SERVICE")
@NamedQuery(name = Service.ALL, query = "SELECT s FROM Service s ORDER BY s.name ASC")
public class Service implements Serializable {
  // ...
}
```

The results are returned and sorted in this case-sensitive order:

```
 Name1, Name3, name2
```

but I want to receive them in the typical alphabetical order:

```
 Name1, name2, Name3
```

I tried to include `ORDER BY LOWER(s.name) ASC`, to sort case insentivie but this is not supported by JPQL parser.

The query is executed by this script in a corresponding DAO, btw:

```
public List<T> findByNamedQuery(@NotNull String namedQueryName, Map<String, Object> parameters, Integer maxResults) {
    TypedQuery<T> query = this.entityManager.createNamedQuery(namedQueryName, getDomainClass());

    if (maxResults != null) {
        query.setMaxResults(maxResults);
    }

    setParameters(parameters, query);
    return query.getResultList();
}
```

How can I achieve the alphabetical order from the results?

Comment: Has been answered here already: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9934494/jpa-perform-case-insensitive-order-by

Comment: No, the solution isn't working at all (see my post). The return value from `select p, lower(p.name)` doesn't match the return value of the recommended entity: `List<T>`

Comment: Then try adding the lower case name as field to the entity and order by that

Comment: You can use that query and map your `List<Object[]>` to list of objects you want.